# Retrieving user's joining date in youtube

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve user's profile information, such as age, location and etc. using YouTube API,Python. 
So far I have succeed to retrieve them all, except the date that the user has joined YouTube.

This information is available in the profile as "Date joined", but I don't know how to extract it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything for joining date because I couldn't find any command and tag for that. for example for location i use 'entry.location.text', or for age 'entry.age.text'. But I don't know what would work for date of joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new v3 data api.

If you have the channel's id, you can call it here:

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCDsO-0Yo5zpJk575nKXgMVA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCDsO-0Yo5zpJk575nKXgMVA&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

If you don't have an API key, you can get one in the Google API Console.

Once you make the API call, the Date Joined field you are looking for is found in items.snippet.publishedAt

Documentation for this API can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt. I couldn't open the first link that you suggested, it opens an error page.But with the clue that you gave me I solved my problem :)

Comment: The first link is the actual api, so if you do not provide it with an API key it won't work.  Can you explain what you did to solve your problem and mark this answer to close the thread?

Comment: I just used GetYouTubeUserEntry and called published tag , 'entry.published'and it gave me back the joined date of the users. And the answer is marked.